# React Change Style of an element from wraped group

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to change the style of an element from a group. I tried to use state/setState but it cause changing all element's style in the group.

```
{hasResults &&
            stockList.map((item, index) => (
              <div
                onClick={(x) => this.selectItem(item)}
                className={isClicked?"stockItem":"stockItemClicked"}
                key={index}
              >
                <img src={item.src.tiny} alt="" />
              </div>
            ))}
```

onClicked function is:

```
 selectItem = (x) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
      this.props.onClick(x);
    } else {
      x.className = "stockItemSelect";
      this.setState({
        isClicked: true,
      });
    }
    //
  };
```

How can i change a style for just one element. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state variable `clickedItem` (initially null) and on click of any item set that item as `clickedItem`
like

```
this.setState({
        clickedItem: item,
      });
```

inside `render` in `map` while applying className, you can check if the `item` === `clickedItem`  and apply respective className.

```
 {hasResults &&
                stockList.map((item, index) => (
                  <div
                    onClick={(x) => this.selectItem(item)}
                    className={item===state.clickedItem?"stockItemClicked":"stockItem"}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <img src={item.src.tiny} alt="" />
                  </div>
                ))}
```

If `item` is an object, assign some unique property like Id to each of them and you can check `item.Id===state.clickedItem.Id`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one element to be clickable, try this

```
const { clicked } = this.state

stockList.map((item, index) => (
    <div
        onClick={() => this.selectItem(item, index)}
        className={clicked === index ? "stockItem" : "stockItemClicked"}
        key={index}
    >
        <img src={item.src.tiny} alt="" />
    </div>
))}
```

onClicked function is:

```
selectItem = (item, index) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        this.props.onClick(item);
    } else {
        item.className = "stockItemSelect";
        this.setState({
            clicked: index,
        });
    }
    //
};
```

Or if you want multiple elements to be clickable, try this

```
const { clicked } = this.state

stockList.map((item, index) => (
    <div
        onClick={() => this.selectItem(item, index)}
        className={clicked['item' + index] ? "stockItem" : "stockItemClicked"}
        key={index}
    >
        img src={item.src.tiny} alt="" />
    </div>
))}
```

onClicked function is:

```
selectItem = (item, index) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        this.props.onClick(item);
    } else {
        item.className = "stockItemSelect";
        this.setState({
            clicked: {
                ...clicked,
                ['item' + index]: true
            }
        });
    }
    //
};
```